# Pandas get data from a list of column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe: `df` and list of column names: `columns` like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['b','b','c','d'],
    'C': ['b1','b2','c1','d2'],
    'B': list(range(4))})

columns = ['A','B']
```

Now I want to get all the data from these columns of the dataframe in one single series like so:

```
b
0
b
1
c
2
d
4
```

This is what I tried:

```
srs = pd.Series()
srs.append(df[column].values for column in columns)
```

But it is throwing this error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'generator'>';
> only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you add a small input/output example?

Comment: @DaniMesejo added sample input/output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
srs = pd.Series(np.ravel(df[columns]))
print (srs)
0    b
1    0
2    b
3    1
4    c
5    2
6    d
7    3
dtype: object
```

Or [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and `drop=True`:

```
srs = df[columns].stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

If order should be changed is possible use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
srs = df[columns].melt()['value']
print (srs)
0    b
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    0
5    1
6    2
7    3
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['b','b','c','d'],
    'C': ['b1','b2','c1','d2'],
    'B': list(range(4))})

columns = ['A','B']

res = pd.Series(chain.from_iterable(df[columns].to_numpy()))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    b
1    0
2    b
3    1
4    c
5    2
6    d
7    3
dtype: object
```